# How to exempt Automated Testing Users from MFA requirement?

Tags: permissions, security, mfa, multi-factor-authentication, permission-set-groups

We are in the process of turning on MFA.  We have enabled it for the appropriate Profiles and it works fine for most users.

We have a couple of automated testing users in the Profiles that have the MFA requirement.  The MFA requirement breaks the automated testing process.  I've tried using a Muting Permission Set assigned to the automated testing users via a Permission Set Group to turn off the MFA requirement for these users, but the Muting Permission Set does not actually remove the MFA requirement for them - they are still prompted to set up MFA.
[image]

I've tried going to the Automated Testing user record to "disconnect" the MFA App Registration, but it just prompts to set up MFA again.  It seems like the Muting Permission Set is not overriding the requirement in the Profile.

How are others exempting automated testing users from the MFA requirement?

Comment: Please define "an automated testing user" - how is it actually used?

Comment: Selenium type automation to perform automated regression testing.

Answer (score 3):

The SFDC [MFA FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s?language=en_US) states

**Is MFA required for RPA or automated testing accounts?**

> No, accounts for test automation tools, such as Selenium™, Cucumber™, or Appium®, and Robotic Process Automation (RPA) systems such as Automation Anywhere®, don't require MFA. These types of accounts aren't likely to be phished. But you should take precautions with the credentials for automation accounts to guard against bad actors using them to gain access to your Salesforce environments. If your RPA or testing tools support automating MFA with time-based one-time passcodes (TOTP) during login, we recommend doing so. Other options include managing automation account credentials via a privileged account management (PAM) system.

You won't be able to use Muting Permission Sets against a Profile's permissions as the [documentation states](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_muting.htm&type=5) it is for use against permissions granted under a Permission Set Group.  There's a lengthy [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/permission-set-groups/mute-permissions-in-permission-set-groups) on Muting Permission Sets

> Muting lets you customize a permission set group by muting (disabling) selected permissions in it. To mute a permission, you add the permission to a muting permission set in the selected permission set group.

**Workarounds**

Option 1 - Move all your MFA permissions to a Permission Set and assign to the *real* users in the profiles.  This will involve some data migration and then subsequent automation when new users are established. Some tools like BetterCloud allow for direct assignment of permission sets when a new user is onboarded at your company

Option 2 (only if you have to)

Create a new Profile for the test automation users called `TestAutomation`. Don't enable MFA in that profile. Grant common permissions in that profile for all such users and use Permission Sets for unique permissions per test automation user.  This will be a maintenance headache and you'll never be quite sure if the profiles have fidelity to real users.

Comment: You are correct that these users do not require MFA, but it doesn't explain how to exempt them.  My QA team is investigating if they can automate MFA in the RPA system, but don't have a solution yet.  Is there a way to mute the MFA requirement for particular users in Salesforce?

Comment: @MikePaisner Can you just not assign the MFA permission set to these users?

Comment: I have more than 1200 active users in 5 Profiles.  MFA should be applied to all of these users except for the 7 automated test users.  I'd like to assign MFA as part of the Profile except for the 7 automated users because this would be much easier to maintain.  Users come and go all the time.  If I assign MFA via a Permission Set, then I need to build automation to add the MFA Permission Set every time a new user is added in one of these Profiles.  Seems like there has to be an easier way.

Comment: @MikePaisner Since SFDC is wanting us to move to permission sets  / permission set groups; new user automation seems like it is a burden to bear at the moment until tools get better. My org has Flows that auto-assign PS and I would have a checkbox for those users that are test automation users so MFA PS assignment can be bypassed.

Comment: Any idea why the Muting Permission Set approach doesn't work?  Isn't this a perfect use case for Muting Permission Sets?

Comment: @MikePaisner Per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_muting.htm&type=5) that I read, Muting PS only works against Permission Set Groups, not profiles; that is you mute Permissions defined in the PSs of a PSG

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the scope of Muting PS.  Assigning the MFA requirement via Permission Set is annoying.  If done manually, it is a maintenance pain.  Assigning PS via automation frequently causes Mix DML errors.  Wish Salesforce would make this easier.